# How to add control in stacklayout of contentview in contentpage?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin.forms. having two projects Android and IOS.

I have one ContentView page with following code

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="slMain" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="#7ABA45">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0,0,20,0" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="lblTitle" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="sl" IsVisible="False" BackgroundColor="White">
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>


// In Behind code(.cs file)

    public ExpandCollapseStackLayout()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) =>
        {
            sl.IsVisible = !sl.IsVisible;
        };
        lblTitle.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
        slMain.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return lblTitle.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            lblTitle.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

I want to add controls in StackLayout named "sl" of contentview in ContentPage at design time.
I dont want to add at runtime

Please suggest me how can I add Control in Contentview stacklayout?

Comment: have you found a solution? I have the same request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code for ContentView:**

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="slMain" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="#7ABA45" >
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0,0,10,0" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label x:Name="lblTitle" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"  />
            <Label Text="{ x:Static local:GrialShapesFont.ArrowDown }" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" Style="{ StaticResource FontIconBase }" FontSize="26" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Frame Padding="10" IsVisible="False" BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="ContentFrame" OutlineColor="Black" HasShadow="False">
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

**CS Code for ContentView:**

```
[ContentProperty("ContainerContent")]
public partial class ExpandCollapseStackLayout : ContentView
{
    public ExpandCollapseStackLayout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) =>
        {
            ContentFrame.IsVisible = !ContentFrame.IsVisible;
        };
        lblTitle.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
        slMain.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
    }

    public View ContainerContent
    {
        get { return ContentFrame.Content; }
        set { ContentFrame.Content = value; }
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return lblTitle.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            lblTitle.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Add Control in ContentPage:**

```
<control:ExpandCollapseStackLayout Title="Demo" Padding="0,10,0,0">
                <control:ExpandCollapseStackLayout.ContainerContent >
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Add Content Here"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </control:ExpandCollapseStackLayout.ContainerContent>
 </control:ExpandCollapseStackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add controls in design time simply declare them in your XAML, example:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="sl" IsVisible="False" BackgroundColor="White">
  <!-- Add here your controls -->
  <Label ... />
  <Button .. />
</StackLayout>
```

If you want to add controls at runtime, you need to do it using your code behind page in C#. Example:

```
void AddControl()
{
  var btn = new Button();
  sl.Children.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: I wrote Like this in content Page

 <control:ExpandCollapseStackLayout Title="Test">
                <StackLayout x:Name="sl" IsVisible="False" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <Label Text="Test"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </control:ExpandCollapseStackLayout>

But it is not working

Please provide me proper example.

Comment: Hard to understand why it is not working, since you do not provide much details. Wild shot. You have  IsVisible="False" change it to  IsVisible="True". Make sure you don't hide/remove your sl control in code behind and make sure that there are no other controls on the top of it.

Comment: Debug your code and check if the event firing twice, why do you add the same gesture recogniser twice on different elements?